# How to add an images on create-react-app to static folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I have a React apps using create-react-app and I'm currently learning about PWA. I want to load an images when offline and I've read some of article that told me to setup on serviceWorker. Should I eject the create-react-app or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Create a Folder in your React Application And paste the image into that folder (eg : images/img.png)

Step 2 : Open your App.js or any File where you want to import that Image

Step 3 : import sampleImage from 'images/img.png'

Step 4 : use the sampleImage Object inside your render() method

```
 <Image
            source={sampleImage}
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              justifyContent: "center",
              width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
              height: Dimensions.get("window").height / 2,
              resizeMode:"center"
            }}
          />
```

Comment: what does that even do when accessing offline?

Comment: When the app is offline / online the above code does look for the images inside the app

Comment: that didn't work, it still not precaching the image when offline

Answer (score 0):

if you need to create a static folder, you must put your folder to the 'public' folder

Comment: check your index.js and change serviceWorker.unregister();
to serviceWorker.register();

Comment: I also did that.